# prepare a data.frame for model fitting, categorical data

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, glm

I have data set that I want to fit a model to, the data looks like this :

```
    id response var1 var2
1   1        0    T    t
2   1        0    L    w
3   1        0    C    b
4   2        1    X    d
5   2        1    Z    v
6   2        1    O    k
7   3        1   NA    n
8   4        0    N    i
9   4        0    I    a
10  4        0    A    e
11  5        0    K    o
12  5        0    G    l
```

each id has one unique response variable, but the categorical variables var1 and var2 can range fom NULL to several values. ( I have many categorical variables, I'm showing just two for simplicity)

I would to have the data in a format where each ID has one row. 
I tried dcast but I could only do it for one variable at the time. 
any ideas?

the model I want to fit is `response ~ .`

Comment: Maybe post an example of desired output? The only way I can think of getting the data you've shown into a one-row-per-id format would be pretty ugly (i.e., one column for every combination of var1 and var2).

Comment: I am trying to use the `glm()` function among other things, so whatever works. I was thinking one column for each value, rather than each combination.

Comment: Well you could try `library(tidyverse); d %>% 
 unite(var_combo, c(var1, var2)) %>% 
 spread(var_combo, response)` where `d` is your dataset, but, like I said, that's pretty ugly and may not be very workable.